# I need help with my ac unit 30hx5 240

Tags: hvac, filter

I moved to this condominium about a year ago and never really new where the filter would have to be place. The ac unit is above me right when I enter the home but there’s no filter there just some installation the old owners had put before me.I’ve tried putting a filter there I feel something is off like it doesn’t seem right or something when I put a filter there, probably the old owners put it there it was to loud and visible with a smell which made sense but I really need to know where to the filter cause my home gets dusty so fast like right when I clean the next day it’s dusty as ever. Please need some help[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: An HVAC filter won't have much effect on how dusty your home gets, if that's the problem you are trying to solve. Its main purpose is to protect the HVAC system, which is a pain to clean out.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that slab of insulation and get a filter for the grill.

Measure the width and length of the inside and get a filter.  You're probably getting so dusty because the HVAC system is trying so hard to suck air it is sucking dust and fibers off of the insulation.